# Have equal background halves in the back of the main button

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, background

I have this main button in the center, and I am trying to have two a button on either side. I am trying to have each button have half of the background but right now one side is overpowering the other. You can see what I mean in the photo below. [image: Example of overpowering photo]

The styling code for the background can be found below. If you need more code or information let me know.

```
.yesIcon {
background: limegreen;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding-top: 80%;
padding-bottom: 80%;
padding-right: 80%;
z-index: 1;
margin-right: -50%;
}
.noIcon {
    background: gold;
    padding-top: 80%;
    padding-bottom: 80%;
    padding-left: 80%;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-left: -50%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center
}
```

The code for creating the boxes and assigning the classes can be found below so you know what box has what class.

```
var br = document.createElement("br")
            var br2 = document.createElement("br")
            var br3 = document.createElement("br")
            var div = document.createElement("div")
            var yesIcon = document.createElement("div")
            var noIcon = document.createElement("div")
            yesIcon.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-check-square-o fa-5x' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
            noIcon.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-ban fa-5x' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
            var uniqueID = Date.now();
            div.id = uniqueID;
            div.className = "wrapper"
            const matchedIDs = [1];
            matchedIDs.push (uniqueID);
            console.log(matchedIDs)
            
           
            matchesID.appendChild(br)
            matchesID.appendChild(br2)
            matchesID.appendChild(div)
            var divID = document.getElementById(uniqueID)
            divID.appendChild(yesIcon)
            divID.appendChild(buttonCreate)
            divID.appendChild(noIcon)
            yesIcon.className = "yesIcon"
            buttonCreate.className = "matchesDIVs"
            noIcon.className = "noIcon"
            matchesID.appendChild(br3)
            sleep(1);
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need each colour to be separate? If not, you can do it with a linear-gradient property in CSS.

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, limegreen 60%, gold 60%);
```

This would set the limegreen up to the 60% line of your element, then the gold from 60% to the end.

Comment: Although that would work for the background colors, I am trying to have both colors be a clickable element. For that reason, both colors are currently different elements behind a div. Is there a way to do that and still have the full side clickable?

Comment: Ok, couple of different options... Use the background: linear-gradient on the main div, then create two clickable divs of width: 60% and width: 40% (not sure if you want an onclick or an a tag or a button, etc. for them)

Other option, create who divs, one that's 60% width with background of limegreen, one that's 40% width with a background of gold, then use relative/absolute positioning or grids to position them?